# Invalid field - new fields added to managed package in custom object

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, administration

EDIT:
When I go to https://workbench.developerforce.com and I do not see the field which I have added, is that due to Managed release installed?

I have installed the Managed package in my org and then I have added few new fields to that custom object and I can see that fields are there but when I try to do SOQL query I get this error:

> INVALID_FIELD: (Address__c)

```
SELECT id,name,Address__c FROM Employee__c
```

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:30 No such column 'Address__c' on entity
>   'Employee__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

when you add new fields to the managed package object you need to go to 
`-->Manage-->Users>Permission Sets --> Object Settings --> select your object --> and check the READ/EDIT`

Then

click on the newly field created and `-->Click on Set Field Level Security` and assign appropriately

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the namespace of the managed package in your query. Assuming that `Employee__c` is the object from the managed package and `Address__c`is a custom field that you added to it, your query should read like

> SELECT id,name,Address__c FROM namespace__Employee__c

replacing `namespace` with the appropriate value

Comment: Yes I have tried with namespace and no avail also as I said in my question I don't even see the new field I have created in workbench.developerforce